# how to get loaded html download file with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

Im trying to use this library https://github.com/hrikrishnankr/Pdf2Html
to upload a pdf and download a html file. I have been successfully able to download html file using

```
function download(filename, text) {
var element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
element.setAttribute('download', filename);
element.style.display = 'none'; 
document.body.appendChild(element);
element.click();
document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

then I have this to get the html from the viewer

```
var data=document.getElementById("viewer").innerHTML;
```

and run the function when button download button is clicked

```
<button id="download" class="toolbarButton download hiddenMediumView" title="Download" tabindex="34" data-l10n-id="download"
            onclick="downloadhtml()">

function downloadhtml() {

var data=document.getElementById("viewer").innerHTML;
download('file.html', data);
}
```

but the file I get is mostly empty div containers with loading

```
<div class="loadingIcon"></div>
```

Supposedly it should already have pdf2html conversion functionality built in. How can I get the html in the viewer after it is done loading and download it in a file?

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery it can be done like this.

```
$('<form />', { action: downloadURL, "id": "downloadForm", method: 'GET', target: '_blank', html: '<input type="hidden" id="file" name="file" value="' + fileURL + '" />'}).appendTo(document.body).submit();
```

Or with simple Javascript first you need to create form element and then provide the download url in the action and submit it.

Comment: No, you have to scroll to load the pages this does not account for that